# What is the difference between sprintf_s and snprintf?

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow

I encountered this question while writing a program that requires the `sprintf` function.

In some cases, using the `sprintf` function can lead to memory overflow and pose a security risk. So, you can use the `snprintf` or `sprintf_s` functions, which are used to avoid these risks.

But the definitions of these two functions are the same. So, why do these two functions exist instead of just one?

```c
int sprintf_s(char *_DstBuf, size_t _DstSize, const char *_Format, ...);
int snprintf(char *__restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char *__restrict__ __format, ...);
```

In the beginning, I thought that the `sprintf_s` function was unique to the Windows library, and I also thought that the `snprintf` function was unique to POSIX. But, in fact, both of these functions are included in the `<stdio.h>` library.

Comment: `int sprintf_s();` from the C spec has signature `char * restrict s, rsize_t n, const char * restrict format, ...`.  Better to use that than `char *_DstBuf, size_t _DstSize, const char *_Format, ...`.

Comment: "But the definitions of these two functions are the same" - you have them *right next to each other* how can you not see that they're different? The bit where they wrote `__restrict__` in one of them isn't a party trick, it has a purpose.

Comment: You are asking about two things—two directions of differences—instead of one. You might want to reconsider the question. The difference between `sprintf` and `snprintf` is primarily that `snprintf` is intended to limit itself to writing into the given array and to return how many bytes are needed to write the string fully. The difference between the `_s` routines and their original counterparts is the `_s` routines are intended to check at runtime that constraints on their parameters are satisfied. `sprintf_s` will not tell you how many bytes are needed; it just tells you you screwed up.

Comment: Also note that Microsoft has its own non-C-standard versions of some `_s` routines. So you should not just as about `sprintf_s` but about the `sprintf_s` in a Microsoft library or the `sprintf_s` in another library that conforms to the C standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of differences between the `snprintf` and `sprintf_s` functions, notably in their return values and how they handle errors.

**Return Values** (barring errors):

- `snprintf` returns the number of characters which *would have been* written to the buffer if the "size" argument were ignored.
- `sprintf_s` returns the number of characters *actually* written.

**Additional Checks**:

The `sprintf_s` function also performs checks that `snprintf` does not, including. The call fails (and returns zero) if any of the following are true:

1. The `%n` format specifier is given.
2. Any of the arguments corresponding to a `%s` format specifier are null pointers.
3. The given "size" argument is zero.

Comment: Actually, I think there is another **major** difference: When the buffer is not large enough for the determined output, `snprintf` will truncate but `sprintf_s` will call a handler which, by default, will raise an exception and (most likely) terminate the program. Unfortunately, I can't verify this as my PC has MSVC (which uses a different definition for `sprintf_s` and I can't get any of the other "Godbolt" C compilers to accept it.

Comment: The default behavior of the constraint handler [is implementation-defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.6.1.1p4). The default contraint handler is not required to raise an exception and terminate the program, but I guess that any sane implementation would do so.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Which is a huge failure in both the way MIcrosoft's non-portable implementation and the very different C-standard Annex K-defined implementation.  For example, a library that wants specific handling of errors can not change the constraint violation/error handler without impacting the entire process.  The constraint handler design has a lot in common with a single `extern int errno;` for getting error reasons in that it's fundamentally broken in any multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 3):

The main differences between `snprintf` and `sprintf_s` are:

1. The function `snprintf` is available on all ISO C compliant platforms, whereas the function `sprintf_s` does not exist on most platforms. This is because compliant platforms are not required to implement Annex K of the standard and most platforms have chosen not to implement it.
2. The function `snprintf` will silently truncate the string if it is too large, whereas the function `sprintf_s` will call the currently installed [contraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s) function.
3. The function `sprintf_s` will perform additional validation of the function arguments (such as checking for a `NULL` pointer) and will call the currently installed constraint handler function if these validations fail, whereas calling `snprintf` with an invalid argument will invoke undefined behavior (i.e. possibly crash the program).

Comment: `snprintf()` will also return the number of bytes needed if the string is too large - a **very** useful feature entirely lacking from `sprintf_s()`.